# API call from searchbar in wordpress

Tags: rest-api, api

I am adding a feature to my website where visitor enters keyword (dynamic), clicks submit in searchbar and an external API gets called. API responds with certain data which is then displayed on page. I am a super newbie so any help from basics would be really appreciated.

Note: keyword search acts as a variable in API

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.